# problem on setting up python on visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After installing Python and Visual Studio code as followed on this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNFgRUD2w68&lc=UgxjG9Bd_Uwm9duwpld4AaABAg

I can't see the reload button in the VS  but there are two button; one is disable, and the other is uninstall. Do you know why I don't have reload button and how to resolve this issue? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to reload the page. Python is already installed. 
Just close the current window near the "Extension: Python".
If for some reason VSCode still can't recognize python files, just close it and open it again.

Answer (score 1):

After finishing your Python file in VS Code, save all changes, head to the terminal and enter the directory of the python file(A directory is where you've saved your file), and type `python example_file.py`.
Of course, you can change the name `example_file.py` to your actual file name.